# Is $(1+x)^m$ a power function by definition?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, definition

**Definition:** A one-term function with a variable as the base and a constant as the exponent. The exponent in the case of a power function is always a constant and a real number.

The general form of a power function is, $f(x)=kx^n$

I know the foregoing definition as the definition of power functions, but i encounter with a function such as $(1+x)^m$, it is also known as binomial function.[The website](https://www.statisticshowto.com/binomial-series/) says that $(1+x)^m$ is a power function, but i think that it does not obey the given definition.

So , can we say that $(1+x)^m$ is a power function, if so,  can you explain please ?

Comment: You can think of it as a power function translated one unit to the left.

Comment: According to your definition of power function it is not. BTW I have never seen the term "power function" being used in math.

Comment: Often, terms like "power function" are used only in teaching, and rarely in practice, and different sources will thus define the term slightly differently without much concern for consistency. This was much more permissible when the writing was confined to books, but now the world of the internet makes such inconsistent usages much more visible. By your definition of power function, this is not a power function, but there are other, different definitions, and you can't expect all definitions to be the same, unfortunately.

Comment: My answer would be "either it actually is, or it is close enough to not make it worth making a big deal out of it". The only time it would be worth it is if you're going to have your homework and tests graded by someone who likes making a big stink over unimportant things. In which case none of our answers matter - you have to go ask that person how they're going to grade, and you'll just have to follow that "ruling" while you're in their class.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### Definitions

It depends on your definition.  The definition given in the question is

> **Definition:** A one-term function with a variable as the base and a constant as the exponent. The exponent in the case of a power function is always a constant and a real number.

The [website in the question](https://www.statisticshowto.com/derivatives/power-rule/) gives a similar definition:

> **Definition:** A *power function* has the form
> $$ f(x) = ax^p$$
> where:
>
> - $a$ and $p$ are constants,
> - $p$ is a real number,
> - and $a$ is nonzero.

Thus, per these definitions, the *only* functions which are power functions are those which can be written in the form
$ x \mapsto kx^m,$
where $k$ and $m$ are real constants.  A function of the form
$$ x \mapsto (1+x)^m$$
is not of this form, hence it is not, by definition, a power function.  It is interesting to note that the cite website is, itself, not even consistent about its use of this definition, as their discussion of the binomial theorem starts with the text

> The binomial series is a type of Maclaurin series for the power function $f(x) = (1 + x)^m$.

Note, however, that it is not necessary to define a power function in this way.  We write definitions in order to clearly communicate ideas and to capture the essential properties of an object or idea we want to talk about.  So, for example, when I teach this material in precalculus classes, I generally give the following definitions:

> **Definition:**  A *primitive power function* is a function of the form
> $$ p : (0,\infty) \to \mathbb{R} : x \mapsto x^m, $$
> where $m$ is a non-zero real number.

It is helpful to study "primitive power functions", since they have similar properties:  they are either monotonically increasing or decreasing (depending on the sign of $p$, their graphs come in only a couple of shapes (basically depending on where $p$ lives relative to $0$ and $1$), and so on.

A more general power function is then something of the form
$$ x \mapsto b\left( \frac{x-h}{a} \right)^m + k, $$
which is just a primitive power function which has been scaled, translated, and (possibility) reflected.  Per *this* definition, the function
$$ x \mapsto (1+x)^m$$
is a power function.

#### Does it Matter?

In higher level mathematics, we are often kind of sloppy about terminology, particularly when it is not terribly important.  I think that Tao has said some [useful words on the "why?" of this](https://terrytao.wordpress.com/career-advice/theres-more-to-mathematics-than-rigour-and-proofs/).  The notion of a "power function" is somewhat useful in calculus (since the power rule is a useful computational tool), but bare "power functions" don't generally pop up that often beyond the pedagogical setting of an introductory calculus class.  Polynomial and exponential functions are much more common.

As such, one probably should not get too caught up on the precise definition of a "power function".  Yes, the *Statistics How To* website is inconsistent in its usage of the term (which might belie some deeper problems with their material, but that's neither here nor there), but it largely doesn't matter, since that isn't really the core of what is being described and discussed.

Answer (score 0):

As you have said, it doesn't look it fits the definition. I think the definition is a bit imprecise here, but if we decide we want to make the function fit the definition, we can rewrite it with a substitution.

Set $w=1+x.$
Then you get $$f(x)=(1+x)^m=w^m=f(w-1).$$
This now fits the criteria nicely.

Alternatively, you can skip a step and simply let the input be $x-1$ to get $$f(x-1)=(1+(x-1))^m=x^m.$$

As mentioned by @csch2, this is then a power function translated one unit to the left.